# How to check if a highlight attribute is displayable on a terminal?

Tags: vim, terminal, terminfo, termcap

I am writing a plugin and need to check if a highlight attribute (bold, italic,
underline and so on) is actually displayable on a terminal.
I tried to check it with termcap. For example of the underline,

```
!empty(&t_us) && !empty(&t_ue)
```

becomes TRUE on xterm, and displayable.
However,
becomes TRUE on win32, but not displayable.
becomes FALSE on nvim, but displayable.

Could someone have a good idea to check it correctly?

Comment: Users can and often do lie to Vim by setting a `$TERM` that doesn't reflect their terminal emulator's capabilities so relying on `&t_xx` alone is certainly not a good idea. If you want your feature to be solid you wild probably have to check for `&t_xx` AND other things like `win32` and possibly other environment variables.

Comment: Even that won't help much, because there's no practical way to see what's actually on the terminal's screen.

Answer (score -1):

Highlighting colors and attributes should be controlable by the user; that's why we have the indirection via `:highlight` groups and bundles of such in the form of *colorschemes*.

That said, for WYSIWYG-rendering like HTML tags, most users probably want italic rendered as italic (and so on...)

Therefore, I would recommend to make this configurable (typicall via `:highlight default ...` so that it can be overridden by users, alternatively via `g:pluginname_attributesForBlah` if this would result in too much duplication for the user). You can still use your heuristics (based on the termcap info or `$TERM`) to provide good configuration defaults. That offers a comfortable default for the majority of plugin users (on common platforms and terminals), but still allows tweaking for special cases or users with special needs (e.g. a visual disability that can't read low contrast or italics well).